# Spring jpa No converter found capable of converting from type AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Car")
@Table(name = "Car")
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CarEntity
{
   private final String identification;
   private final String attribute_2;
   private final String attribute_3;
   private final String attribute_4;
   private final String attribute_5;
   private final String attribute_6;
}
```

The Dto has two attributes more.

My Dto:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class CarDto
{
   private final String identification;
   private final String attribute_2;
   private final String attribute_3;
   private final String attribute_4;
   private final String attribute_5;
   private final String attribute_6;
   private final String childCarIdentification;
   private final String parentCarIdentification;
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "CarRelation")
@Table(name = "CarRelation")
@IdClass(CarRelationId.class)
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CarRelationEntity
{
   @Id
   private String carIdentification;
   @Id
   private String subCarIdentification;
}
```

The `CarRelationId`:

```
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CarRelationId implements Serializable
{
   private String carIdentification;
   private String subCarIdentification;
}
```

The CarRelationDto:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class CarRelation
{
   private final String carIdentification;
   private final String subCarIdentification;
}
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface JpaCarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, String>
{
   @Query("""
         SELECT        c.identification, c.attribute_2, c.attribute_3, c.attribute_4,
            c.attribute_5, c.attribute_6, cr.subCarIdentification AS childCarIdentification, cr_1.carIdentification AS parentCarIdentification
         FROM            Car c LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                  CarRelation cr ON cr.carIdentification = c.identification LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                  CarRelation AS cr_1 ON c.identification = cr_1.subComponentIdentification
         WHERE        (c.identification = :identification )
    """)
   Optional<CarDto> findByIdentification(@Param("identification ") String identification );
```

The error:

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [path.to.object.Car]
```

How can i transform the Sql-Result to `CarDto` Object other how the pass the Result to a Dto Object

Answer (score 0):

Use @SqlResultSetMapping as explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping)